# Merging data frame conditionally into one data frame on the basis of it existing

Tags: r, data-mining

I have data frames that only exist depending on a certain condition so sometimes not every single possible data frame exists. It is based on how many unique values there are in a column of a data set. I would like to have generalized code that can update over time so as more unique values exist over time, I can add them into a conglomerate data frame. The following code creates the object containing the unique values.

```
x <- month(data$created_at)
```

```
y <- unique(month(data$created_at))
```

Here is the code that would create the data frames based on the values of y

```
if (any(y == 4)) {
april<-data.frame(get_nrc_sentiment(data2[x==4])))
}

if (any(y == 3)) {
march_sentiment<-data.frame(get_nrc_sentiment(data2[x==3])))
}

if (any(y == 2)) {
february_sentiment<-data.frame(get_nrc_sentiment(data2[x==2])))
}
#january
if (any(y == 1)) {
january_sentiment<-data.frame(get_nrc_sentiment(data2[x==1])))
}
```

If for some data values in march do not exist, but in others, they do, how do I write code so it only creates a large data frame with the sentiments that exist

For reference, here is what I am doing now

```
monthly_sentiment<-data.frame(january_sentiment,february_sentiment,march_sentiment,
                              april_sentiment,may_sentiment,june_sentiment,
                              july_sentiment,august_sentiment)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to know exactly what you need since you haven't shown us an example dataset, or told us what you mean exactly by "merge" or "conglomerate".

But given what you've said, one approach could be to assign data frames to a single list if the data frames exist, and do nothing when they don't exist. Then, you could merge all the datasets in your list using `Reduce` and `merge`, or the mechanism you prefer.

```r
datasets <- list()
datasets[['january']] <- data.frame(idx = 1:2, jan = 1:2)
datasets[['february']] <- data.frame(idx = 2:3, feb = 2:3)
datasets[['april']] <- data.frame(idx = 0:1, apr = 0:1)

Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), datasets)
#>   idx jan feb apr
#> 1   0  NA  NA   0
#> 2   1   1  NA   1
#> 3   2   2   2  NA
#> 4   3  NA   3  NA
```